# How can I read the names of the SelectedItems in a listbox and output them to a textbox?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, listbox

I have a multi selection `listbox` that I want the user to be able to select 1-52 items from and then have those items be displayed in a text box.

It's easy enough to display the currently selected item using

```
txtBox.text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

But I'm stumped on how to have this display every item that's selected. I've found how `SelectedItems` stores in `SelectedObjectsCollection`, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the selected items names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply iterate over the collection:

```
private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;

    foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
    {
        textBox1.Text += item.ToString();
    }
}
```

Or one-liner code with [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8):

```
private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Join(",", listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<string>());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it had to be simple! Works perfectly!